# Why I receive this exception while creating a custom Realm for GlassFish Server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm creating a custom login module for GlassFish Server. This is because I need to authenticate by using a web service.

I have added the two JARs from the `GlassFish_Server\glassfish\modules` folder to the custom login module classpath.

This is the `CustomLoginModule` class:

```
package loginmodule;

import com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class CustomLoginModule extends AppservPasswordLoginModule {

    @Override
    protected void authenticateUser() throws LoginException {

        String[] roles = {"admin"};
        commitUserAuthentication(roles);
    }

}
```

And this is the `CustomReal` class:

```
package loginmodule.loginmodule;

import com.sun.appserv.security.AppservRealm;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.BadRealmException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.InvalidOperationException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.NoSuchRealmException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.NoSuchUserException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Properties;

public class CustomRealm extends AppservRealm {

    /** JAAS Context parameter name */
    public static final String PARAM_JAAS_CONTEXT = "jaas-context";

    public static final String AUTH_TPYE = "Authentication done by checking user at table USERS on database";

    @Override
    public void init(Properties properties) throws BadRealmException, NoSuchRealmException
    {
        String propJaasContext = properties.getProperty(PARAM_JAAS_CONTEXT);

        if (propJaasContext != null) setProperty(PARAM_JAAS_CONTEXT, propJaasContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthType()
    {
        return AUTH_TPYE;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<?> getGroupNames(String usid) throws InvalidOperationException, NoSuchUserException
    {
        return Collections.enumeration(getGroups());
    }

    public static List<String> getGroups() {
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
        s.add("admin");
        return s;
    }
}
```

As you can see these two classes does not have complicated login to perform the actual login process...

...**but** the problem is when I perform a validation in the GlassFish Server console for adding the actual JAR generated from the custom login project. This is the error message which appears in GlassFish:

An error has occurred
Creation of Authrealm CustomRealm failed. java.lang.ClassCastException: loginmodule.CustomLoginModule cannot be cast to com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm java.lang.ClassCastException: loginmodule.CustomLoginModule cannot be cast to com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm

Any help, suggestion, etc. for this issue?

Additional details:

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)

Comment: is that all you have ??? I don't see anywhere `Realm` or `CustomLoginModule` class

Comment: @Ravi I have updated the question details.

Comment: `This is the CustomLoginModule class` But code says `public class LoginModule` ?? . Makes sure you post complied question

Comment: Please add the `pom.xml` files of your JAR files.